# Flushing output buffer in C (cgi)

Tags: c, cgi, buffer, stdout

The following code:

```
int z = 0;
while(z < 4)
{
printf("iteration %d\n",z);
sleep(1);
z++;
}
```

Works fine and stdout buffer is flushed every second if running the program from command line. However, when I try to access the program in a web browser (server - apache on linux, compiled executable (with gcc) handled through cgi), the content is displayed only after 4 seconds and not "step by step". I am looking for something like PHP's `ob_flush()`. *And, by the way, is cgi the best way of processing compiled C executables?*

**Update:** <s>neither `fflush(stdout)` nor `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` is working!!!</s> Works great after disabling `mod_deflate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand your question correctly, but in C you can

- Flush after each print (`fflush`)
- Disable buffering (`setbuf`, `setvbuf`)

  ```
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); /* this will disable buffering for stdout */
  ```

If these won't work, then either something else is doing buffering or buffering is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [`fflush`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fflush.html) `stdout` after your `printf`.